# how to specify multiple file extensions in rgrep?

Tags: emacs

I tried *.{cc,hh} but it doesn't work (this works for lgrep though). i also tried the method suggested her e http://compgroups.net/comp.emacs/searching-multiple-file-types-with-rgrep/95027 but it seems the interactive mode doesn't allow me to input space. Any idea?

Comment: Never used rgrep, but try *\.[cc|hh]

Comment: <kbd>C-q</kbd><kbd>SPC</kbd> to enter a space

Answer (score 10):

`*.cc *.hh` is correct. The find command will then use something like:
`\( -iname \*.cc -o -iname \*.hh \)`

(If you supply a prefix argument, you can view/edit the command before it is executed.)

You can enter the space using `quoted-insert`: <kbd>C-q</kbd><kbd>SPC</kbd>, or `just-one-space`: <kbd>M-SPC</kbd>

Comment: I always forget about `quoted-insert` despite using it frequently in `replace-string`. Good answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was (in despair) rolling an elisp solution:

```
(defun mrgrep (pattern extensions dir)
     (interactive "ssearch for: \nsextensions (space separated, no *): \nD")
     (setq includes (mapconcat (lambda (ext)
                                 (concat (format "--include=\"\\*%s\"" ext)))
                               (s-split " " extensions)
                               " "))
     (setq cmd (format "grep -ir %s %s %s"
                       includes
                       pattern
                       (concat dir "*")))
     (setq cmd (read-from-minibuffer "run grep like this: " cmd))
     (compilation-start cmd 'grep-mode)
     )
```

but phils explained how to enter the space !